# Red Hat packages list description

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, redhat

**Hello,**

Is there any difference between package kernel-rt-debug and kernel-debug? What -rt stand for?

Comment: rt stands for realtime

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the following link:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/7.4_release_notes/new_features_real-time_kernel

The RT stands for real time and allows a small increase in the productivity in kernel tuning/debugging as against the standard kernel-debug.